# How to display node name in Action script 3 xml

Tags: actionscript-3

My xml is like below

```
<rat>
    <to>tt</to>
    <from>ggg</from>
    <heading>hhhhh</heading>
    <body>jjj</body>
</rat>
```

My AS3 code is

```
var example:XML = new XML(event.target.data);
_label.text = example[0].rat[0][nodeName];
addChild(_label);
```

I want to display the data like

```
to  = tt
from = ggg
```

how can i do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var example:XML = <rat>
    <to>tt</to>
    <from>ggg</from>
    <heading>hhhhh</heading>
    <body>jjj</body>
</rat>;

for each (var node:XML in example.*)
{
    trace(node.localName(), "=", node);
}
```

Comment: trace is not working in my IE . is there any other way to display the result on screen

Comment: yeah, trace is an internal debugging function. if you want to display the result, you'll need to create a textfield and set the "text" or "htmlText" property to the output. var t:TextField = new TextField(); t.text = node.localName() + "=" + node; addChild(t);

Answer (score 1):

you want: xml.branch.node.name();

see [XML in Flash CS3/AS3](http://www.kirupa.com/developer/flashcs3/using_xml_as3_pg4.htm)